# Quotient algebra is involutive: do we need the ideal do be self-adjoint?

Tags: abstract-algebra, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a $*$-algebra, i.e. an algebra $A$ together with a map $*: A \to A$ such that

$$(a+ \lambda b)^* = a^* + \overline{\lambda} b^*$$
$$a^{**}= a$$
$$(ab)^* = b^* a^*$$

My book then claims that if $I$ is an ideal of $A$ satisfying $I=I^*$, then $A/I$ becomes a $*$-algebra for:

$$(a+I)^*= a^* + I$$

I proved this but I can't see where the hypothesis that $I=I^*$ is used. Can this hypothesis be ommited?

Comment: If $A$ is a C*-algebra and $I$ is a closed ideal of $A$, then $I=I^*$ automatically.

Comment: As a subset of $A$, we have $(a+I)^*=a^*+I^*$.  Thus, in order to ensure that $(a+I)^*=a^*+I$, we would need $I=I^*$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be omitted, because without the assumption $I=I^*$ the involution $(a+I)^*=a^*+I$ is not well defined. Every time when we define a function on equivalence classes which does something with the representatives we have to prove the definition doesn't depend on the choice of the representatives.

So here, suppose $a+I=b+I$ and we have to prove that in that case $(a+I)^*=(b+I)^*$, i.e we have to show that $a^*+I=b^*+I$. And this is indeed true, because: ($a+I=b+I$ implies $a-b\in I$)

$a^*-b^*=(a-b)^*\in I^*=I$

So we used the assumption $I^*=I$ here.

Without this assumption the involution would not be well defined, because we would have some $a\in I$ such that $a^*\notin I$. In that case we would have $a+I=0+I$ but $(a+I)^*=a^*+I\ne 0+I=(0+I)^*$.